# Delete Method in PHP 7 not recieving parameters

Tags: php, angularjs, rest, ionic-framework

we are programming a Restful API to be called from an ionic app. We are sending from angular service with this code:

```
      .service('ServiceName', function($http) {
       return {
           borrarAlumno: function(par) {
               var link = "http://localhost/ws/index.php";
               return $http.delete(link, {
                   id: par.id
               })
           }
       }
   })
```

When we try to read id parameter from php we dont get anything. This is the code we are using:

```
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400'); // cache for 1 day
}


// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS");

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:{$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

    exit(0);
}

$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
print_r($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
exit();
```

We have tried with similar code to get parameters with PUT, GET and POST methods and it worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

This php is called form another PHP:

```
class AlumnosAPI
{
    public function API()
    {
        header('Content-Type: application/JSON');
        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

        switch ($method)
        {
          case 'GET':
              include('get.php');
              break;
          case 'POST':
              include('post.php');
              break;
          case 'PUT':
              include('put.php');
              break;
          case 'DELETE':
              include('delete.php');
              break;
          default:
              echo 'NOT SUPPORTED';
              break;
        }
    }

}
```

Edit 2: full code of delete.php

```
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']))
  {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
  }


    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS')
  {

      if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
          header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS");

      if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
          header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:{$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

      exit(0);
  }

  $valor['borrado'] = 0;

  include('conexion.php');

  $id = "";

  //parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $delete);
  $input = file_get_contents('php://input');
  print_r($input);
  exit();

  foreach (array_keys($delete) as $key)
  {
    $$key = $delete[$key];
  }

  if ($id != "")
  {
    //PREPARAMOS LA SENTENCIA SQL
    $sql = "DELETE FROM Alumnado WHERE `ID`=?";

    $resultado1=$conexion->prepare($sql);

    $resultado1->bind_param('i', $id);

    $resultado1->execute();

    $valor['borrado'] = $resultado1->affected_rows;
  }

  $datos=json_encode($valor);

  echo $datos;
```

Comment: you speak of DELETE, but where in the PHP code you refer to DELETE? only OPTIONS I see

Comment: We redirect to this PHP from another PHP code like this: [code]case 'DELETE':
              include('delete.php');
              break;[/code]

Comment: go ahead and share the code of delete.php and tell us if you verified that delete.php is been called actually

Comment: delete.php is the code I posted erlier. It's verified that delete.php is called, I tried to echo a string and it worked. Anyway I post full code of delete.php en my second edit.

Comment: so, the first part of delete.php is skipped, as request method equals delete. Then you should end up at print_r($input). What does it say?

Comment: Nothing, an empty string.

Comment: in delete method get the id via `$_GET['id']`

Comment: $_GET is an empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular doesn't send a request body for `DELETE` so you're going to have to read id from the URL.

```
.service('ServiceName', function($http) {
       return {
           borrarAlumno: function(par) {
               var link = "http://localhost/ws/index.php";
               return $http.delete(link, {
                   params : {id: par.id}
               })
           }
       }
   })
```

get the id via `$_GET['id']` instead of `file_get_contents('php://input');`